# Requirements for convexity of isolated minima

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F} \in \mathscr{C}^1(X, \mathbb{R}^+ \cup {0})$, where $X$ is a separable Hilbert space. Consider any isolated minimum $\phi \in X$ ($\phi$ has a non-zero neighborhood in which it is the only local minimum of $F$).

Prove (or disprove) that $F$ is convex over some non-zero neighborhood of $\phi$. Does the answer change if $X$ was a finite dimensional Hilbert space instead?

The motivation is finding the minimal requirements needed by an element $\phi$ to be a locally convex minimum of $F$.